# What variable/attribute changes when you hit play on an HTML5 video controller?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-video

I'm using HTML5 video tags in my webpage. I have a small "Watch Video" button that opens a modal displaying this video. Everything works as intended. I am, however, trying to determine what changes in the HTML document (or possibly the DOM?) when I hit the controller's play button.

The goal in determining this is to have the video begin playing automatically once the modal is revealed which I plan to do with a small JS script. Also, when I close the modal window, I will have it disappear.

I did a few Google searches and started to see people discussing creating custom controllers for these videos which I feel is unnecessary - I want to utilize/modify what is already in existence.

To summarize: What is happening when I hit the play/pause controllers in an HTML5 video?

Answer (score 0):

The W3C has a [handy `<video>` interface](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) that shows how the properties and events on a video element change and fire as you interact with it.

As you can see from that demo, the major things that occur when you play a video are:

- the video's `paused` attribute is set to `false`
- the video emits a `play` event

If the video has `preload` value of `"none"` (as this one does), then the video will begin loading when the user presses play, which triggers a few other events, e.g, the `canplaythrough` event will eventually fire, the `buffered` attribute will continue to change as the video loads, etc.